# Regex match only numbers that are exactly 5 digits long - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript -
I want to extract only the numbers that are exactly 5-digits long.

`let example = "The quick brown 22 333 44 55555`

In this case, I want it to match and give me  and 55555

Edit: I figured it out.
Since I want EXACTLY five digits:
`.match(/(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)/g)`

This ensures it's exactly five and no other numbers that exceed it

Comment: very basic regular expression `/\d{5}/`

Comment: Where did `12345` and `55555` come from? For one there is no `1` in the example string.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it.

```
(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeQgpF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is:

```js
/\b\d{5}\b/
```

- `\b` for a word boundary (start of a word here)
- `\d` for a digit
- `{5}` for 5 times
- `\b` again for a word boundary (end of a word here)

An example:

```js
const example = "hello c12345 df444 3444, 55555";

const matches = example.match(/\d{5}/g);

console.log(matches);
// => [ '12345', '55555' ]
```

Comment: This also matches 123456 so this is wrong

Comment: Totally right, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
"[0-9]{5}"
[0-9] // match any numbers between 0 to 9
{5} // match exactly 5 times
```

Comment: This also matches 123456 so this is wrong